# OxyPlot not refreshing in VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, graph, oxyplot

I was using Visual Studio to chart data when I ran into a problem with the logarithmic X-Axis. I have now turned to OxyPlot, however, I am running into huge issues with getting my data to populate. I switched from the windows forms to WPF, so this could be a XAML issue with binding (unsure). Essentially I took their very limited example in VB.net and can easily reproduce it. What I am struggling with is reproducing dynamic plotting with OxyPlot. Here is my code so far:

Sample: (http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-wpf-vb.html)

```
Public Sub New()
        Model = New PlotModel()

        Model.Title = "Simple example"
        Model.Subtitle = "using OxyPlot in VB.NET"

        Dim series1 = New LineSeries()
        series1.Title = "Series 1"
        series1.MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(0, 0))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(10, 18))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(20, 12))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(30, 8))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(40, 15))

        Dim series2 = New LineSeries()
        series2.Title = "Series 2"
        series2.MarkerType = MarkerType.Square
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(0, 4))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(10, 12))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(20, 16))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(30, 25))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(40, 5))

        Model.Series.Add(series1)
        Model.Series.Add(series2)
    End Sub
```

Then I attempt to add more data to simulate dynamically loading data. I also am aware that I must use invalidate() and that Update() is deprecated. I added a button to the form and give it another series to add to the chart upon click.

Button Click:

```
Private Sub test_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles test.Click


        Dim series3 = New LineSeries()
        series3.Title = "Series 3"
        series3.MarkerType = MarkerType.Square
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(20, 20))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(21, 21))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(22, 22))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(23, 23))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(24, 24))
        Model.Series.Add(series3)
        Model.InvalidatePlot(True)
    End Sub
```

Here is also their lovely reference to updating their dataPlot: http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/common-tasks/refresh-plot.html#examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event handler, you need to add `series3` to your `Model` before calling `InvalidatePlot` i.e.

```
Model.Series.Add(series3);
Model.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

**Update**

Also, you need to make sure your PlotModel notifies the view (XAML) of your changes. If I use [the example from Oxyplot documentation](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-wpf-vb.html) as an example (the one you specified), I'd modify the code as such:

```
Public Class MainViewModel Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private mmodel As PlotModel

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()

        Model = New PlotModel()

        Model.Title = "Simple example"
        Model.Subtitle = "using OxyPlot in VB.NET"

        Dim series1 = New LineSeries()
        series1.Title="Series 1"
        series1.MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(0, 0))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(10, 18))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(20, 12))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(30, 8))
        series1.Points.Add(New DataPoint(40, 15))

        Dim series2 = New LineSeries()
        series2.Title="Series 2"
        series2.MarkerType = MarkerType.Square
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(0, 4))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(10, 12))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(20, 16))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(30, 25))
        series2.Points.Add(New DataPoint(40, 5))

        Model.Series.Add(series1)
        Model.Series.Add(series2)

    End Sub

    Property Model() As PlotModel
        Get
            Return mmodel
        End Get
        Set(value As PlotModel)
            mmodel = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Model")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub test_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles test.Click

        Dim series3 = New LineSeries()
        series3.Title = "Series 3"
        series3.MarkerType = MarkerType.Square
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(20, 20))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(21, 21))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(22, 22))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(23, 23))
        series3.Points.Add(New DataPoint(24, 24))
        Model.Series.Add(series3)
        Model.InvalidatePlot(True)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: My mistake on missing that, however even with your updated code it still does not fire the plot update.

Comment: Mmh, OK... then maybe as you mentioned at the beginning of your question it could be an issue with the data binding in your XAML... your `test_Click` function needs to notify your View (the XAML) that `PlotModel` has changed using `PropertyChangedEventHandler`. In your XAML, when doing the binding to your PlotModel, specify: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` - I'll update my answer

Comment: harveyAJ, I appreciate your help, however, I actually struggle the most with XAML(for I am new to it). Do you think you could post an example of the XAML for me to better reference your comment above?

Comment: @AustinEfnor I created a small project on GitHub: https://github.com/harveyAJ/VbNetWpfApp

Comment: I use VS2017 but that should also work with earlier versions.

Comment: all of your code was fantastic and made me further understand the issues at hand, but it hasn't fixed my main issue. I cannot seem to get my dynamic data to stay in scope or initialized, whatever it may be. It will lose data when add series is called even though all of the data is added to the new series and the series is added to the model.

Comment: I'll have a look into this when I get a bit of time! I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, does the data you add by clicking your button overwrites previously added data?

Comment: Essentially, I run my program and it gets all of this data, then calls `addSeries()`. From there the first line is to call `plotData()`, it then goes in and adds the data to the series, series to plot. After that function it then calls `Model.IndalidatePlot(True)`. The problem is that my code seems to add it all, then goes back through and adds it again when `addSeries()` is called as the last step in the program to update the plot. I cannot figure out how to fix this.